# Integrating liferay 5.2 EE5 with solr 3.x or later

Tags: solr, liferay

I have liferay 5.2 EE5 integrated with solr 1.4. I would like to upgrade solr to newer version (for example: 3.6). Does anyone know how to do it? Or maybe someone integrated liferay 5.2 with solr 3.6 or newer?

I will be grateful for any help.

Regards.